# Why is $\arctan(\tan(25\pi / 4)) = \pi/4$?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

Why is $\arctan(\tan(25\pi /4)) = \pi/4$, and how can I get from the expression on the left to the one on the right?

Comment: Notice that $\frac{25\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{4} + 6\pi$.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: By the *definition* of $y=\arctan x$ we have $-\frac {\pi}{2}<y<\frac {\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ${\tan(x)}$ function is periodic, meaning it will not be injective, thus will not have an inverse. **Unless you restrict the domain**.

For example, in your case

$${\tan\left(\frac{25\pi}{4}\right)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$$

So if you apply the inverse function - what value do we take? Both ${\frac{25\pi}{4}}$ and ${\frac{\pi}{4}}$ give the same answer under the tangent function. So **we** are the ones who must decide which value we take. In exactly the same way that we decide ${\sqrt{4}=2}$, and not ${-2}$ (even though both ${(-2)^2=4}$ as well). The decision we make is called the "principle values". For example we say the principle square root of four is two.

We take the principle values of ${\arctan(x)}$ to be from the interval ${\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$, and since ${\tan\left(\frac{25\pi}{4}\right)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$ and ${-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \frac{\pi}{4}\leq \frac{\pi}{2}}$, that's the answer you will get to the expression:

$${\arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac{25\pi}{4}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

Comment: So if the answer is already in $(- \pi /2, \pi/2)$ it stays the way it is. For instance, if I have $arctan(tan(25 / 7\pi ))$ (which is already in the interval where arctan is the inverse of tan) the answer will be $25/7 \pi$?

Comment: @Salman exactly that yes :) But outside of that inverval, since you get a "repetition" - we only take the principle value on the interval ${\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$. This choice is technically arbitrary - I could choose my principle values to be from ${\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right)}$ - but taking the ${\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$ interval is the most natural one

Comment: I always appreciate polite and respectful users. Thank you is the minimum for me.

Answer (score 2):

We can apply the identity
$$\arctan{(\tan{(x)})}=x$$
only for $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. So we just need to use the fact that
$$\tan{(25\pi/4)}=\tan{(\pi/4)}$$
by periodicity of the tangent.

Answer (score 0):

Since the tangent function is periodic with period $\pi$, $\tan\left(\frac{25\pi}4\right)=\tan\left(\frac\pi4\right)$. And since $\arctan$ is the inverse of the restriction of $\tan$ to $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ and since $\frac\pi4\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$,$$\arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac\pi4\right)\right)=\frac\pi4.$$